# Adding more than 3 sections on a SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, modern-experience

What is the better approach to add more than 3 sections on a SharePoint modern page?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, we are not able to create a custom layout in SharePoint modern page. So we simply cannot create a 4 section layout

Answer (score 0):

As of now SharePoint Online only supports maximum three columns section on modern pages.

But if you want to add 4th section on your page, you can leverage the **vertical section** in SharePoint Online.

**Add a vertical section**:

1. Go to the page where you want to add a vertical section.
2. If you're not in edit mode already, click **Edit** at the top right of the page.
3. Hover your mouse below the title area of the page to the far left, or above or below an existing web part to the far left of the page, and you'll see a line with a circled **+**, like this with a tool tip that says **Add a new section**.
4. Click **+**.
5. Under Section layout, select **Vertical section**.

**Official documentation**: [Add sections and columns on a SharePoint modern page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-sections-and-columns-on-a-sharepoint-modern-page-fc491eb4-f733-4825-8fe2-e1ed80bd0899)

**Notes**:

- Vertical sections are currently available only on the right side of the page.
- Length of vertical sections is adjusted based on the content on the page, growing or shrinking with the length of content in non-vertical sections.
- You cannot have a full-width column and a vertical section on the same page.